# MySql query - return page and sub-page in two different column while page and sub-page name store in same column

Tags: mysql

My question is -
I have a table which name is 'Pages',
and table structure is like that :

```
    -------------------------------------------------
    page_id | parent_page_id | page_name
        1     |    null        | Home
        2     |    null        | About Us
        3     |    null        | Services
        4     |     2          | Who we are
        5     |    null        | Contact Us
        6     |     3          | Photography
   -------------------------------------------------
```

Now i want to display result in this format by using only MySql query:

```
    -----------------------------------------------------
    ID | Page Name   | Sub Page Name
    1  |  Home       |    N/A
    2  |  About Us   |  Who we are
    3  |  Services   |  Photography
    4  |  Contact Us |    N/a 
   -----------------------------------------------------
```

I hope you can understand what my question is.

**Any comment/suggestion/solution will be helpful for me.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How are the values in DB?

If all values in same row then it's a simple query.

If they are in different rows then you need to use `case` statement.

Comment: Values are in different rows, can you give me  an example of case statement

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you manage the ID with rendering function then you main problem can be solved  with a selfjoin

```
select a.page_name  as `Page Name`, ifnull(b.page_name as `Sub Page Name`, 'N/a')
from Pages as a 
left join Pages as b on a.parent_page_id = b.page_id
;
```